# Difficult request to elasticsearch on c #

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm trying to make a complex query to use ElasticSearch Nest library

I'm need to make fulltext search to fields Text and NormalizedText and to make filter by date range and list tag. For example I will want Text or NormalizedText contain "keyword" and CreatedDate was range 01.01.2016 - 01.06.2016 and sntag was tag1 or tag2 or tag3

I try to make this request, but I recieve error: "{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccesful low level call on POST: /post_index/elasticitem/_search?pretty=true}" How to make this request is correct?

> ```
>         var result = es_cli.Client.Search<ElasticItem>(s =>
>          s.Skip(skip)
>         .Sort(c => c.Descending("createdDate"))
>         .Take(itemonpage)
>         .Index(index)
>         .Query(f1 =>
>              f1.DateRange(x => x.Field(fff => fff.CreatedDate).GreaterThanOrEquals(filter.start))
>              && f1.DateRange(x => x.Field(fff => fff.CreatedDate).LessThanOrEquals(filter.end))
>              && (f1.Match(e => e.Field(ee => ee.Text).Query(searchString)) || f1.Match(e => e.Field(ee =>ee.NormalizedText).Query(searchString)))
>              && f1.Terms(x=>x.Field(xx=>xx.Sntag).MinimumShouldMatch(1).Terms(filter.SourceIDs))
>              )
>         );
> ```

filter.start and filter.end it is DateTime. searchString is string. filter.SourceIDs is String array

PS. Debug info

Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccesful low level call on POST: /post_index/elasticitem/_search?pretty=true

## Audit trail of this API call:

- BadResponse: Node: http://192.168.14.57:9200/ Took: 00:00:01.6093332

  ## ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"

## OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line 138

## Request:

## Response:

Comment: May you share info from `result.DebugInformation`?

Comment: I add DebugInformation

Comment: what version of NEST are you using and which version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: elasticsearch-2.1.0 Nest 2.0.4